# What is the difference between use a paint and set paint to null when canvas.drawBitmap()

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have noticed that each `canvas.drawBitmap()` has a `Paint` parameter .
And API doc always says that *May be null. The paint used to draw the bitmap.*
But what is the difference between put `null` in that and not?
I tried that with a custom paint, but it seems have no difference between put paint null.

Thanks for any response.

Comment: Try setting your custom paint with antialiasing, dithering or a number of other options for controlling how bitmaps are drawn.  The colour of the paint is not what's important (it's not used when drawing a bitmap) but the paint options are, see the Paint documentation for options.